# Strange BackgroundMode

Tags: eclipse, swt

The `BackgroundMode` of `container` is `SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT` :

```java
Shell shell = new Shell() ;
shell.setSize( 300, 100 ) ;
shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;

Composite container = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE ) ;
container.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, true ) ) ;
container.setBackgroundMode( SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT ) ;
container.setBackground( new Color( 255, 0, 0 ) ) ;
System.out.println( "container : " + container.getBackgroundMode() ) ;
System.out.println( "container : " + container.getBackground() ) ;

Button button = new Button( container, SWT.NONE ) ;
button.setText( "button" ) ;
System.out.println( "button : " + button.getBackground() ) ;

Label label = new Label( container, SWT.NONE ) ;
label.setText( "label" ) ;
System.out.println( "label : " + label.getBackground() ) ;

shell.open() ;
```

```
container : 1
container : Color {255, 0, 0, 255}
button : Color {240, 240, 240, 255}
label : Color {255, 0, 0, 255}
```

[image]

The results are in line with expectations.

The `BackgroundMode` of `container` is `SWT.INHERIT_FORCE` :

```java
Shell shell = new Shell() ;
shell.setSize( 300, 100 ) ;
shell.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;

Composite container = new Composite( shell, SWT.NONE ) ;
container.setLayout( new GridLayout( 2, true ) ) ;
container.setBackgroundMode( SWT.INHERIT_FORCE ) ;
container.setBackground( new Color( 255, 0, 0 ) ) ;
System.out.println( "container : " + container.getBackgroundMode() ) ;
System.out.println( "container : " + container.getBackground() ) ;

Button button = new Button( container, SWT.NONE ) ;
button.setText( "button" ) ;
System.out.println( "button : " + button.getBackground() ) ;

Label label = new Label( container, SWT.NONE ) ;
label.setText( "label" ) ;
System.out.println( "label : " + label.getBackground() ) ;

shell.open() ;
```

```
container : 2
container : Color {255, 0, 0, 255}
button : Color {255, 0, 0, 255}
label : Color {255, 0, 0, 255}
```

[image]

The result is ridiculous. The `Background` of `button` is `{255, 0, 0, 255}`, but the real effect is not.

Is this a bug ?

Comment: Button backgrounds depend a lot on what the native control supports. For example, testing this on macOS the background is used regardless of the background mode.

Comment: It's acceptable that different platforms have different effects. But in the second scenario, the button says that it's red when asked for its backgroundColor, but the screen capture shows it isn't actually red as painted to the display...

Comment: Same on macOS the button reports a different colour to what is actually displayed - you can try reporting a bug on https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt

Comment: I see this [issue already reported to SWT](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/618) with the same strange title. Consider deleting the issue or giving a self-answer that references the issue.